# onchange does not trigger when the <option> are from sql using php mysqli_query

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I wanna put a drop down box that contains countries from the database.
and the second drop down box should populate with the states on the first drop down box. ( I have done this using hard coded HTML on the "add location function" but this is the search function now.)

```
<select name="COUNTRY" onchange="GetState();" class="VASELECT" style="WIDTH: 200PX;">

<?php 
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT DISTINCT country FROM t1 where country != ""');
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){

echo "<option value=\">". $row['country']."\">" . $row['country'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="STATE" onchange="GetCity();" class="VASELECT">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="" selected="selected"></option></select>
```

It executes the query with no problems. And the first drop down box shows the countries from the database but it cannot detect the `onchange` funtion and the second drop down has nothing to show. The `GetState()` should work. I do not know why. the javascript code is very long so I'm pasting just a chunk of it here

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> //get state inside

function GetState() {
    document.OPTIONS.CITY.length = 1;
    document.OPTIONS.CITY.options[0].text = "";
    document.OPTIONS.CITY.options[0].value = "";
    document.OPTIONS.STATE.length = 1;
    document.OPTIONS.STATE.options[0].text = "";
    document.OPTIONS.STATE.options[0].value = "";       

    if (document.OPTIONS.COUNTRY.value == "United States") {

        document.OPTIONS.STATE.length = 53;

            document.OPTIONS.STATE.options[1].text = "Alabama";
            document.OPTIONS.STATE.options[1].value = "AL";

            document.OPTIONS.STATE.options[2].text = "Alaska";
            document.OPTIONS.STATE.options[2].value = "AK";

               }

      }
//extends up to 3thousand lines of code (it contains all countries in the world. LOL)
</script>
```

Comment: Anything in developers console?

Comment: Your options look wrong - you have an extra closing bracket in your quotes, try `echo "<option value=\"". $row['country']."\">" . $row['country'] . "</option>";` so your value is probably not matching what you would expect

Comment: I am wondering if this in not a timing issue?  The fact that you say it extends 3000 lines of code.  So the <option> field is rendered before the function actually finishes running.  Thus returns no values.

Comment: Do you want to populate the second drop down from database via ajax or what?

Comment: @u_mulder ummm i do not know how to use that. im still a newbie on web programming. (should have learnt this first before anything else. :( )

Comment: @jae.phoenix umm i dont think so sir. cause i tried just 20 lines of java script to check if timing issue has issues.

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari i jsut wanna populate it with the plain old java script :)

Comment: @u_mulder OOOH you mean the inspect element and then the debugger? 


    `<select name='country'><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in <b>/var/www/html/search.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably in the HTML itself. TAke a look at this line:

```
echo "<option value=\">". $row['country']."\">" . $row['country'] . "</option>";
```

This should be:

```
echo "<option value=\"". $row['country']."\">" . $row['country'] . "</option>";
```

Another thing that I notice is that you don't have:

```
<select name="STATE" onchange="GetCity();" class="VASELECT">
```

Above your `while` loop